# How to set formula to get value from specific sheet

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I set formula in sheet1 cell (1,9) to get the value from other sheet through google apps script. Where "sheet" is a variable, I need to get value from specific sheets. The code below shows "=sheet!B1" rather than "=6!B1".

```
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=0");
var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  
var sheet;
sheet = 6;
var sheet = sheet.toString();
sheet1.getRange(1,9).setFormula('sheet!B1')
}
```

Comment: `setFormula(\`${sheet}!B1\`)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Google Apps Script uses JavaScript as programming language
2. `setFormula` requires a string as parameter.

Considering the above you could use any string manipulation technique available using the JavaScript version supported by the runtime that your project is using.

Among other techniques you coul use:

1. String concatenation operator i.e. `sheet + '!B1'` (if you are using the old (Mozilla Rhino) or the new runtime (Chrome v8) )
2. String templates i.e. `` `${sheet}!B1` `` (only if you are using the new runtime (Chrome V8) )

Comment: Works with your 1st suggestion.

Comment: It only works when I tested by function my Function { }. I have no idea why it shows "#REF!" in the cell when I use function doGet(e) {  } and pop out "unsolved sheet name xx ". I also tried to click on the cell and then ENTER, amazing is it does work. How to correct it?

Comment: Please post a new question including a [mcve]